# Can I use disengage as an action and then something else as a bonus action on the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, actions

What the title says. Provided that I have something I can use as a bonus action, can I use it and then disengage as my action?

Comment: Have you read the relevant rules in the PHB or basic rule? Can you give us more of an idea of what's confusing you? Is there a particular reason why you think you can or can't do this?

Comment: This seems like a very basic question. Is there some complication that we're missing that makes the answer not straightforward?

Comment: No, sorry. Just had a misunderstanding with my DM.

Comment: @YvesReginaldMangon it helps to provide context with your question. As you can see, at the moment this has acquired a few downvotes because it shows a lack of research effort since it can be easily answered if one has read the rules. By adding in details about the misunderstanding with the DM and *showing* that you've tried to find the answer yourself e.g "my DM said I can't do this but I can't find anything in the rules that would prevent it" then your question may be better received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing preventing you from doing this under normal circumstances.

On your turn you can, as per page 189 of the PHB:

- Take one action, or more with certain features.
- Move a distance up to your speed.
- Take one bonus action, if applicable.

So unless you're under some kind of effect that stops you from taking one of these actions, e.g. being *incapacitated,* then you are certainly able to take the disengage action and use a bonus action.

Answer (score 3):

Some kinds of bonus actions are tied to certain actions. For example attacking with your off-hand as a bonus action via two-weapon fighting or using the hilt of your pole-arm to attack as a bonus action are both tied to taking the attack action as your action.

But for bonus actions that have no limiter as to when it can be used you can then use it before disengaging.

You could cast a bonus action spell before disengaging, for example. But you could not make the two weapon fighting bonus offhand attack because you can only use it when taking the attack action with your main hand. This has nothing to do with disengage.